# Will US customs have records of someone entering the US (in 1989) and exiting (in 1991)? It was before machine-readable passports

Tags: visas, usa

I assume there won't be any records available as it was over 25 years ago. Does ayone know anything more concrete than my guess? To be clear, the person overstayed their visa by 18 months and wants to return to the US for a holiday.

Comment: When getting a visa or applying for an ESTA you get asked if you have ever overstayed. You should never lie! Be honest, it was a long time ago , prove they are a changed person and have something to go home for.

Comment: Did you fill out an I-94 form in 1989?  (No, in not certain whether they even existed in those days.)  If so, the record of your arrival is probably stored in an archive somewhere.

Comment: @TheZealot The problem is, you don't know what they know... a risky suggestion.  I think an overstay ending in 1991 is unlikely to cause any problems today, even if they know about it, but lying about it and them detecting the lie is very likely to cause problems.

Comment: The rule is do not venture information unless asked. They have most of the information, the only question is whether it is readily available to them or in some paper files in some archives. It's long ago enough many reasonable immigration officers would overlook and evaluate your current personal circumstances. At the same time many immigration officers can be very unreasonable, particularly in the current climate.

Comment: @TheZealot the problem is that the traveler will most likely have to submit a visa application or ESTA application well before reaching an immigration officer, in which case he will have to answer a question such as "Have you ever stayed in the United States longer than the admission period granted to you by the U.S. government?"

Comment: @phoog you don't have to answer a predefined list of questions if you enter overland without an ESTA. And most of the time you won't be asked about previous overstays by the border guards.

Comment: @JonathanReez you also don't have to answer the questions if you're Canadian or eligible for some other reason to enter without a visa independently of the VWP.

Answer (score 4):

> Does anyone know anything more concrete than my guess?

By default you should presume that the US government does know and build up your strategy accordingly. Your options are therefore:

1. **Best approach:** apply for a US visa, honestly mentioning your previous overstay. Assuming you're an otherwise law-abiding individual with a stable source of income its highly likely you will receive a visa regardless of your previous overstay.
2. **Risky approach:** fly to Canada and then enter the US overland, without applying for an ESTA or a visa. At the land border you are *usually* not asked about previous overstays and the crossing experience is quite smooth. But if you *are* asked, the best strategy would be to tell the truth and hope for the best. In the worst case scenario you can just drive back to Canada and enjoy a holiday there instead.